# Remote Sender and Consumer JMS using HTTP in Wildfly 8.2

Tags: http, jms, wildfly, remote-client

I can not make it work even in http.

I followed all the documentation I found on the websites of Wildfly and HornetQ.

I configured standalone.xml as more important excerpts below:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging:2.0">
    <hornetq-server>
        <journal-file-size>102400</journal-file-size>
        <connectors>
            <http-connector name="http-connector" socket-binding="http">
                <param key="http-upgrade-endpoint" value="http-acceptor"/>
            </http-connector>
            <http-connector name="http-connector-throughput" socket-binding="http">
                <param key="http-upgrade-endpoint" value="http-acceptor-throughput"/>
                <param key="batch-delay" value="50"/>
            </http-connector>
        </connectors>

        <acceptors>
            <http-acceptor http-listener="default" name="http-acceptor"/>
            <http-acceptor http-listener="default" name="http-acceptor-throughput">
                <param key="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                <param key="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
            </http-acceptor>          
        </acceptors>

        <security-settings>
            <security-setting match="#">
                <permission type="send" roles="JMSRole"/>
                <permission type="consume" roles="JMSRole"/>
                <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="JMSRole"/>
                <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="JMSRole"/>
            </security-setting>
        </security-settings>
        <jms-connection-factories>
            <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory">
                <connectors>
                    <connector-ref connector-name="http-connector"/>
                </connectors>
                <entries>
                    <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory"/>
                </entries>
                <ha>true</ha>
                <block-on-acknowledge>true</block-on-acknowledge>
                <retry-interval>1000</retry-interval>
                <retry-interval-multiplier>1.0</retry-interval-multiplier>
                <reconnect-attempts>-1</reconnect-attempts>
            </connection-factory>
        </jms-connection-factories>
        <jms-destinations>
            <jms-queue name="JMSOrderDownloadPage">
                <entry name="java:/jms/queue/JMSOrderDownloadPage"/>
                <durable>true</durable>
                <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/JMSOrderDownloadPage"/>
            </jms-queue>
            <jms-queue name="DLQ">
                <entry name="java:/jms/queue/DLQ"/>
                <durable>true</durable>
            </jms-queue>
        </jms-destinations>
    </hornetq-server>
</subsystem>
```

I tried running the code below. Everything works correctly yet I ask the connectionFactory to create a new connection.

```
   HornetQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = null;
    Connection connection = null;
    Session session = null;
    MessageProducer producer = null;
    MessageConsumer consumer = null;
    Destination destination = null;
    TextMessage message = null;
    Context context = null;

    try {
        // Set up the context for the JNDI lookup
        final Properties env = new Properties();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://www.xyz.com:8080");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "jmsuser");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "pass1");
        env.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
        context = new InitialContext(env);

        connectionFactory = (HornetQConnectionFactory) context.lookup("jms/RemoteConnectionFactory"); //The lockup function correctly. Including authentication.
        destination = (Destination) context.lookup("java:/jms/queue/JMSOrderDownloadPage");
        connection = connectionFactory.createConnection("jmsuser", "pass1"); //At this time the error occurs following below, after the code.
        session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        producer = session.createProducer(destination);
        connection.start();
        int count = Integer.parseInt("1");
        String content = System.getProperty("message.content", "Hello, World!");
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            message = session.createTextMessage(content);
            producer.send(message);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

The StackTrace is:

javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory   at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:673) at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createConnection(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:112) at br.com.voelivre.finder.queue.search.alert.Start.main(Start.java:106) **Caused by: HornetQNotConnectedException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=HQ119007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]**   at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:905) at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:669) ... 2 more

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: Wildfly is listening in www.xyz.com:8080?

Comment: Hello Federico!

No... www.xyz.com is an example of host. It was only to show that the wildlfy is exposed on the Internet listening on port 8080.

I managed to find the solution. I shared in the answer below.

Hug, Tássio

Answer (score 2):

After testing various configurations without success thank God I managed to find the solution. I share with the community so that it can help other friends in the future.

My standalone.xml was as follows (highlighted the most important points):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:2.2">
    <extensions>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.connector"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.deployment-scanner"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.ee"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.ejb3"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jaxrs"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jdr"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jmx"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jpa"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jsf"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.logging"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.messaging"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.naming"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.pojo"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.remoting"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.sar"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.security"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.transactions"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.weld"/>
        <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.batch"/>
        <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.io"/>
        <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.undertow"/>
    </extensions>

    <management>
        <security-realms>
            **<security-realm name="ManagementRealm">
                <authentication>
                    <local default-user="$local" skip-group-loading="true"/>
                    <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authentication>
                <authorization map-groups-to-roles="false">
                    <properties path="mgmt-groups.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authorization>
            </security-realm>
            <security-realm name="ApplicationRealm">
                <authentication>
                    <local default-user="$local" allowed-users="*" skip-group-loading="true"/>
                    <properties path="application-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authentication>
                <authorization>
                    <properties path="application-roles.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authorization>
            </security-realm>**
            <security-realm name="SSLRealm">
                <server-identities>
                    <ssl>
                        <keystore path="/xxx.../...tomcat.keystore" keystore-password="the password"/>
                    </ssl>
                </server-identities>
            </security-realm>
        </security-realms>
        <audit-log>
            <formatters>
                <json-formatter name="json-formatter"/>
            </formatters>
            <handlers>
                <file-handler name="file" formatter="json-formatter" path="audit-log.log" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/>
            </handlers>
            <logger log-boot="true" log-read-only="false" enabled="false">
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="file"/>
                </handlers>
            </logger>
        </audit-log>
        <management-interfaces>
            <http-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm" http-upgrade-enabled="true">
                <socket-binding http="management-http"/>
            </http-interface>
        </management-interfaces>
        <access-control provider="simple">
            <role-mapping>
                <role name="SuperUser">
                    <include>
                        <user name="$local"/>
                    </include>
                </role>
            </role-mapping>
        </access-control>
    </management>


    <profile>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:2.0">
            <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <formatter>
                    <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
                </formatter>
            </console-handler>
            <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
                <formatter>
                    <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
                </formatter>
                <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
                <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                <append value="true"/>
            </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
            <logger category="com.arjuna">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
                <level name="DEBUG"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="sun.rmi">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="jacorb">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="jacorb.config">
                <level name="ERROR"/>
            </logger>
            <root-logger>
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                    <handler name="FILE"/>
                </handlers>
            </root-logger>
            <formatter name="PATTERN">
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
            </formatter>
            <formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
            </formatter>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:batch:1.0">
            <job-repository>
                <in-memory/>
            </job-repository>
            <thread-pool>
                <max-threads count="10"/>
                <keepalive-time time="30" unit="seconds"/>
            </thread-pool>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:2.0">
            <datasources />
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:2.0">
            <deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="5000"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:2.0">
            <spec-descriptor-property-replacement>false</spec-descriptor-property-replacement>
            <concurrent>
                <context-services>
                    <context-service name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/context/default" use-transaction-setup-provider="true"/>
                </context-services>
                <managed-thread-factories>
                    <managed-thread-factory name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/factory/default" context-service="default"/>
                </managed-thread-factories>
                <managed-executor-services>
                    <managed-executor-service name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/default" context-service="default" hung-task-threshold="60000" core-threads="5" max-threads="25" keepalive-time="5000"/>
                </managed-executor-services>
                <managed-scheduled-executor-services>
                    <managed-scheduled-executor-service name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/scheduler/default" context-service="default" hung-task-threshold="60000" core-threads="2" keepalive-time="3000"/>
                </managed-scheduled-executor-services>
            </concurrent>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:2.0">
            <session-bean>
                <stateful default-access-timeout="5000" cache-ref="simple" passivation-disabled-cache-ref="simple"/>
                <singleton default-access-timeout="5000"/>
            </session-bean>


            <pools>
                <bean-instance-pools>
                    <strict-max-pool name="slsb-strict-max-pool" max-pool-size="20" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
                    <strict-max-pool name="mdb-strict-max-pool" max-pool-size="20" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
                </bean-instance-pools>
            </pools>
            <caches>
                <cache name="simple"/>
                <cache name="distributable" passivation-store-ref="infinispan" aliases="passivating clustered"/>
            </caches>
            <passivation-stores>
                <passivation-store name="infinispan" cache-container="ejb" max-size="10000"/>
            </passivation-stores>
            <async thread-pool-name="default"/>
            <timer-service thread-pool-name="default" default-data-store="default-file-store">
                <data-stores>
                    <file-data-store name="default-file-store" path="timer-service-data" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/>
                </data-stores>
            </timer-service>
            <remote connector-ref="http-remoting-connector" thread-pool-name="default"/>
            <thread-pools>
                <thread-pool name="default">
                    <max-threads count="10"/>
                    <keepalive-time time="100" unit="milliseconds"/>
                </thread-pool>
            </thread-pools>
            <default-security-domain value="other"/>
            <default-missing-method-permissions-deny-access value="true"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:io:1.1">
            <worker name="default"/>
            <buffer-pool name="default"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:2.0">
            <cache-container name="web" default-cache="passivation" module="org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan">
                <local-cache name="passivation" batching="true">
                    <file-store passivation="true" purge="false"/>
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="persistent" batching="true">
                    <file-store passivation="false" purge="false"/>
                </local-cache>
            </cache-container>
            <cache-container name="ejb" default-cache="passivation" module="org.wildfly.clustering.ejb.infinispan" aliases="sfsb">
                <local-cache name="passivation" batching="true">
                    <file-store passivation="true" purge="false"/>
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="persistent" batching="true">
                    <file-store passivation="false" purge="false"/>
                </local-cache>
            </cache-container>
            <cache-container name="hibernate" default-cache="local-query" module="org.hibernate">
                <local-cache name="entity">
                    <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>
                    <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="local-query">
                    <transaction mode="NONE"/>
                    <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="timestamps">
                    <transaction mode="NONE"/>
                    <eviction strategy="NONE"/>
                </local-cache>
            </cache-container>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jaxrs:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jca:2.0">
            <archive-validation enabled="true" fail-on-error="true" fail-on-warn="false"/>
            <bean-validation enabled="true"/>
            <default-workmanager>
                <short-running-threads>
                    <core-threads count="50"/>
                    <queue-length count="50"/>
                    <max-threads count="50"/>
                    <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
                </short-running-threads>
                <long-running-threads>
                    <core-threads count="50"/>
                    <queue-length count="50"/>
                    <max-threads count="50"/>
                    <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
                </long-running-threads>
            </default-workmanager>
            <cached-connection-manager/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jdr:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.3">
            <expose-resolved-model/>
            <expose-expression-model/>
            <remoting-connector/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jpa:1.1">
            <jpa default-datasource="" default-extended-persistence-inheritance="DEEP"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jsf:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging:2.0">
            <hornetq-server>
                <security-enabled>true</security-enabled>
                <journal-file-size>102400</journal-file-size>

                <connectors>
                    <http-connector name="http-connector" socket-binding="http">
                        <param key="http-upgrade-endpoint" value="http-acceptor"/>
                    </http-connector>
                </connectors>

                <acceptors>
                    <http-acceptor http-listener="default" name="http-acceptor"/>
                </acceptors>

                <jms-connection-factories>
                    <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory">
                        <connectors>
                            <connector-ref connector-name="http-connector"/>
                        </connectors>
                        <entries>
                            <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory"/>
                        </entries>
                        <ha>true</ha>
                        <block-on-acknowledge>true</block-on-acknowledge>
                        <retry-interval>1000</retry-interval>
                        <retry-interval-multiplier>1.0</retry-interval-multiplier>
                        <reconnect-attempts>-1</reconnect-attempts>
                    </connection-factory>
                </jms-connection-factories>


               <security-settings>
                    <security-setting match="#">
                        <permission type="send" roles="JMSRole"/>
                        <permission type="consume" roles="JMSRole"/>
                        <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="JMSRole"/>
                        <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="JMSRole"/>
                    </security-setting>
                </security-settings>


                <address-settings>
                    <address-setting match="#">
                        <dead-letter-address>jms.queue.DLQ</dead-letter-address>
                        <expiry-address>jms.queue.ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
                        <expiry-delay>-1</expiry-delay>
                        <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
                        <max-delivery-attempts>10</max-delivery-attempts>
                        <max-size-bytes>10485760</max-size-bytes>
                        <page-size-bytes>2097152</page-size-bytes>
                        <page-max-cache-size>5</page-max-cache-size>
                        <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
                        <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
                        <last-value-queue>false</last-value-queue>
                        <redistribution-delay>-1</redistribution-delay>
                        <send-to-dla-on-no-route>false</send-to-dla-on-no-route>
                    </address-setting>
                </address-settings>


                <jms-destinations>
                    <jms-queue name="JMSOrderDownloadPage">
                        <entry name="java:/jms/queue/JMSOrderDownloadPage"/>
                        <durable>true</durable>
                        <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/JMSOrderDownloadPage"/>
                    </jms-queue>
                    <jms-queue name="DLQ">
                        <entry name="java:/jms/queue/DLQ"/>
                        <durable>true</durable>
                    </jms-queue>
                    <jms-queue name="ExpiryQueue">
                        <entry name="java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"/>
                        <durable>true</durable>
                    </jms-queue>
                </jms-destinations>


            </hornetq-server>
        </subsystem>


        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:2.0">
            <remote-naming/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:pojo:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:remoting:2.0">
            <endpoint worker="default"/>
            <http-connector name="http-remoting-connector" connector-ref="default" security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:2.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:sar:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.2">
            <security-domains>
                <security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional">
                            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                        </login-module>
                        <login-module code="RealmDirect" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="jboss-web-policy" cache-type="default">
                    <authorization>
                        <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                    </authorization>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="jboss-ejb-policy" cache-type="default">
                    <authorization>
                        <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                    </authorization>
                </security-domain>
            </security-domains>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:transactions:2.0">
            <core-environment>
                <process-id>
                    <uuid/>
                </process-id>
            </core-environment>
            <recovery-environment socket-binding="txn-recovery-environment" status-socket-binding="txn-status-manager"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:1.2">
            <buffer-cache name="default"/>
            <server name="default-server">
                <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" proxy-address-forwarding="true"/>
                <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="SSLRealm"/>
                <host name="default-host" alias="localhost" default-web-module="voelivre-webservice-1.0.war"/>
            </server>
            <servlet-container name="default">
                <jsp-config/>
                <websockets/>
            </servlet-container>
            <handlers>
                <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
            </handlers>
            <filters>
                <response-header name="server-header" header-name="Server" header-value="WildFly/8"/>
                <response-header name="x-powered-by-header" header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="Undertow/1"/>
            </filters>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:weld:2.0"/>
    </profile>

    <interfaces>
        <interface name="management">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="public">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="unsecure">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
    </interfaces>


    <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
        <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}"/>
        <socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}"/>
        <socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>
        <socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
    </socket-binding-group>   </server>
```

**To test the configuration I used the following Java code:**

```
import java.util.Properties;


import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.JMSContext;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;


import org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory;


public class TestJMS {


  public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException, JMSException {


  HornetQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = null;
  Connection connection = null;
  Session session = null;
  MessageProducer producer = null;
  MessageConsumer consumer = null;
  Destination destination = null;
  TextMessage message = null;
  Context context = null;


  try {
  final Properties env = new Properties();
  env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
  env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://yourserver.com:8080");
  env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "jmsuser");
  env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "your password");
  context = new InitialContext(env);


  connectionFactory = (HornetQConnectionFactory) context.lookup("jms/RemoteConnectionFactory");


  System.out.println("lookup: jms/RemoteConnectionFactory success!");


  destination = (Destination) context.lookup("java:/jms/queue/JMSOrderDownloadPage");


  System.out.println("lookup: java:/jms/queue/JMSOrderDownloadPage success!");


  JMSContext createContext = connectionFactory.createContext("jmsuser", "your password", JMSContext.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);


  System.out.println("connectionFactory.createContext success!");


  createContext.createConsumer(destination);


  System.out.println("createContext.createConsumer success!");


  connection = connectionFactory.createConnection("jmsuser", "your password");


  System.out.println("connectionFactory.createConnection success!");


  session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
  producer = session.createProducer(destination);


  System.out.println("session.createProducer success!");


  connection.start();


  int count = Integer.parseInt("1");
  String content = "Hello, World!";


  // Send the specified number of messages
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  message = session.createTextMessage(content);
  producer.send(message);


  System.out.println("Message sent successfully: " + message);
  }


  } catch (Exception e) {


  e.printStackTrace();


  } finally {
  if (context != null) {
  context.close();
  }


  // closing the connection takes care of the session, producer, and consumer
  if (connection != null) {
  connection.close();
  }
  }


  }


}
```

Comment: one more question though, where do I configure `jmsuser` ?

Comment: @victor You can use wildfly/bin/add-user to do that.  For the user to be able to work with JMS, you can add the role of 'guest'.  See wildfly/standalone/configuration/settings.xml for the list of permissions that the 'guest' role has.

Comment: @victor In this answer, it looks like the 'guest' role has been renamed to 'JMSUser'.